# Print all pods along with cpu requirements kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I want to print a list of all my pods with the CPU requirements in a column

I'm pretty sure its something like
`kubectl get pods 'spec.containers[].resources.limits.cpu'`

Can someone please give me the correct syntax?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the pods (in the default namespace) and their CPU Limit with the following command.

```
kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\t"}{.spec.containers[].resources.limits.cpu}{"\n"}{end}'
```

We use the JSONPath output with the `-o=jsonpath` flag, and provide it with the data we want to extract.

You can find more details on using the JSONPath output at https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/

Answer (score 18):

You can also use the below command to get the cpu limit. It is cleaner than using jsonpath.

```
kubectl get po -o custom-columns="Name:metadata.name,CPU-limit:spec.containers[*].resources.limits.cpu" order by cpu limit with `--sort-by=".spec.containers[*].resources.limits.cpu"`
```

Answer (score 10):

Try the following commands.

Replace `cpu` with `memory` to get the memory requests and limits as well.

```
CPU Requests
--------------
kubectl get po --all-namespaces \
 -o=jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{.metadata.namespace}:{.metadata.name}{'\n'}{range .spec.containers[*]}  {.name}:{.resources.requests.cpu}{'\n'}{end}{'\n'}{end}"
 
CPU Limits
-----------
kubectl get po --all-namespaces \
 -o=jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{.metadata.namespace}:{.metadata.name}{'\n'}{range .spec.containers[*]}  {.name}:{.resources.limits.cpu}{'\n'}{end}{'\n'}{end}"
```

Comment: This jsonpath is better the other answers since it shows limits for *every* of potentially many container in the pod together with the *container* name

Answer (score 2):

This is the table with CPU Request / Limit and Memory Request / limit

```
kubectl get po -o custom-columns="Name:metadata.name,CPU-limit:spec.containers[*].resources.limits.cpu, CPU-request:spec.containers[*].resources.requests.cpu, memory-limits:spec.containers[*].resources.limits.memory, memory-request:spec.containers[*].resources.requests.memory" --namespace=<your-namespace>
```

Comment: This one delivers great results. Best one by far.